# php foreach (class->function as $val) doesn't return array

Tags: php, foreach

I've a class's function I use on a foreach loop. I can return a value (even if it's an array) but not an associative array

```
foreach ($this->myfunction($param1,$param2) as $val){
var_dump($val);
}

private function myFunction($param1,$param2){
  $returnArray = [];
  $settingArray = [];
  ...
  return $returnArray; //works but I need $settingArray
  return ['returnArray'=>$returnArray,'settingArray'=>$settingArray]; //fails: returns only $returnArray array (not associative array $val['returnArray'])
  return array($returnArray,$settingArray]; //fails: returns only $returnArray array
}
```

I can assign values in class for this, but I want to avoid this and also I'm trying to understand why there is this error.
Thank you.

I would like to get the 2 arrays in foreach $val

Comment: It all seems to work as expected, as far as I can see - demo: https://3v4l.org/DXDIf . It returns the contents of both the arrays. What exactly were you expecting to see instead? (P.S. Whilst it's good that you've reduced the code down a bit, please make sure it's definitely still a [mre] of your issue. See also [ask] and the [tour] as you're new, as well. You can [edit] your post. Thanks)

Comment: Thank you for your code example and help. I could figure out my error as I put an exit after first dump.

Comment: Ah ok. So the code you showed us in the question was not the code you were testing with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is problem with the private function which you have used. Whenever you are trying to return an associative array, return the array specifying key and their values. These keys can then be used to catch the values. Check my demo below:

```
<?php

  class MyClass{
    public $param1;
    public $param2;
    public function concatVal($param1, $param2){
        foreach ($this->myfunction($param1,$param2) as $val){
            var_dump($val);
        }
    }

    private function myFunction($param1, $param2){
      $status = "";
      $message = "";
      $returnArray = [];
      $settingArray = [];
      $newWord = "some new word";
      $newWordInMiddle = $param1." ".$newWord." ".$param2;
      $newWordInEnd = $param1." ".$param2." ".$newWord;
      $status = "success";
      $message = "done";

      //return Array
      $returnArray = [
        'status' => $status,
        'message' => $message
      ];

      //settings Array
      $settingArray = [
        'newWordInMiddle' => $newWordInMiddle,
        'newWordInEnd' => $newWordInEnd
      ];

      //returning associative array here
      return array(
        'returnArray' => $returnArray,
        'settingArray' => $settingArray,
      );

    }
  }

  $myObj = new MyClass;
  $myObj->concatVal("Hello", "There");
?>
```